# Yii framework bootstrap - Geting TbEditableColumn enabled attribute to use an expression rather than a boolean value

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii

Is there a way to get the `TbEditableColumn` enabled attribute to use an expression rather than a boolean value (ie: true)

The following is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
array(
  'class' => 'bootstrap.widgets.TbEditableColumn',
  'name' => 'description',

  'editable' => array(
       'type' => 'textarea',
   'url' => $this->createUrl('classification/update'),
   'placement' => 'top',
       'enabled' => '($data->status > 0) ? true : false;',
  )
),
```

It should be noted that this works with the visible attribute available when using the `bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn` as follows:

```
array(
'class' => 'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
'deleteConfirmation' => 'Are you sure you wish to delete this classification?',
'template' => '{delete}',

'buttons'=>array(
    'delete' => array(
    'visible' => '($data->status > 0) ? true : false;',
)
),
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't set the 'value' of the column - read the code [here](https://github.com/clevertech/YiiBooster/blob/master/src/widgets/TbEditableColumn.php):
Instead of enabled, have you tried with 'apply'=>true ?